# Hibernate ManyToMany id column by referencedColumnName not working

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-security, many-to-many

This is not supposed to happen, as many people have used the similar cases many many times.  I'm developing a Spring Root/Security app, have a user table joining a role table, with a unidirectional many-to-many map.

My user class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myuser", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" }) })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // was GenerationType.AUTO
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
...
```

My role class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "role" }) })
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
...
```

Tables are auto created in DB (Postgresql) without a problem with correct constraints.  But, after successfully inserted a new user, with populated Role table, when search for a user by the email, I got the following error:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [
select u.email, r.role from myuser u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) 
where u.email=?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column u.user_id does not exist
```

Notice that I did use "referencedColumnName" in the join table/column annotations.  Why Hibernate still generate u.user_id and r.role_id, instead of u.id and r.id?  What's wrong?  Something to do with the Postgres dialect?

And, as expected, if I changed the ids to @Column(name = "user_id") and @Column(name = "role_id"), then it works fine.  But, why?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. In my case, the column "user_id" does not exist anywhere in my database but for some reason, when I am trying to make a join between my "user" and "authorities" table, hibernate generates a field called "user_id" despite my use of the referencedColumnName attribute.